# Renaming a file in the same directory yields DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: c#, windows

This problem is only affecting *some* of our users. Basically, we're doing a File.Move operation to rename a file, and it's throwing a DirectoryNotFoundException. The affected users are in a Remote Desktop Services environment, so I'm pretty sure that's contributing to the issue, but I don't know how.

The code downloads an image to a temp file, and then renames it. It looks like this:

```
void WriteImageData(string tempfile) {
    // tempfile points to a new file in an existing temp subdirectory
    // e.g. C:\Users\rogern\AppData\Local\temp\images\myfile.bmp

    var part = tempfile + ".part";
    using (var writer = File.Create(part)) {
        StreamDownloadImage(writer, this.documentnumber); // blocking operation
    }
    File.Delete(tempfile); // in case the destination file already exists. This does not throw an exception
    File.Move(part, tempfile); // this is the part that fails
}
```

The stack trace looks like this:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
    at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
    at <mynamespace>.WriteImageData(String tempfile)
```

The image download is a blocking operation and I know that it's working - I see the file in the target directory, and I can load it in an image viewer. I've tried calling File.Exists on the source path (part) immediately prior to File.Move, and it always says that the file does exist. The destination path (tempfile) is in the same folder (as you can see from how the download path is derived).

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: This morning the problem has stopped occurring. No code changes were made. I'm still stumped regarding the original cause, so if you've got ideas I'd love to hear them!